# WindowsError: [Error 183]: Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

I am making a simulation that handles accounts (usernames and passwords).

Since there is a `sign-up` function, I need to keep the account database updated.

And I resorted to creating text file to export if there is new account, and just use `thread` to import that textfile using `while True:` and put `time.sleep(1)`.

Every account will result in creation of folders under the username.

And now, when I run the program, sometimes, it is just fine, flawless.

but sometimes, it raises `WindowsError: [Error 183]` at creation of folders.

Any ideas?

The code is too long since it has GUI and `.jpeg` files as images..

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, this will be a quick one:

[asking google](http://www.google.fr/search?q=WindowsError:%20%5BError%20183%5D&oq=WindowsError:%20%5BError%20183%5D) is always a good idea

[Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19416456/windowserror-error-183-cannot-create-a-file-when-that-file-already-exists) is referenced there

[Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8990725/error-183-when-using-python-os-rename) also

Comment: Can you please share actual solution instead of posting links only?